# Sub exponentially hard OWF , PRF and iO

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-function, one-way-function, software-obfuscation, io

I'm currently reading the work "[Obfuscation of probabilistic circuits and Applications](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/882.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi4zpfg8ZLTAhUHqY8KHeecDUAQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNEh2tIbgZjGPXVDguIzYRBEnyLpmQ&sig2=5exG0ILQxtJwN6EjFf1iFQ)' by Canetti Lin Tessaro and Vaikuntanathan 2015. It says sub exponentially hard OWF implies 
sub exponentially hard PRF ( puncturable PRF) and later again proves that sub exponentially hard PRF ( puncturable PRF) + sub exponentially hard iO $\implies$ pIO(probabilistic circuits).

I'm really confused with what the author means by the term "subexponentially hard" and is it a weather or a stronger assumption when it comes to the OWF or iO.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45424/io-implies-fhewithout-circular-security-assumption)?

Comment: Note that there is a mistake in the question: subexp prf does not imply subexp iO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficiently computable function $f:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow\{0,1\}^*$ is said to be $(s,\epsilon)$-one-way if for every adversary $\mathsf{A}$ of size* at most $s=s(|x|)$ the probability $\Pr\left[{\mathsf{A}(f(x))\in f^{-1}(x)}\right]$ is at most $\epsilon=\epsilon(|x|)$, where the probability is over uniform distribution on the domain and the random coins of $\mathsf{A}$.

The standard one-wayness assumption is that $s=poly(|x|)$ and $\epsilon=negl(|x|)$ . A one-way function is subexponentially-hard if for a fixed constant $0<c<1$, it is $(2^{{|x|}^c},2^{-{|x|}^c})$-one-way. Note that the latter implies the former and is, therefore, a stronger assumption.

Similar definitions apply for the other primitives too.

*Here, size refers either to the run-time if $\mathsf{A}$ is a probabilistic Turing machine, or the circuit-size in case $\mathsf{A}$ is a circuit.

Comment: They will become equivalent if ​ $\omega \hspace{.02 in}(1)$ ​ bits of non-uniformly are allowed, but otherwise, $\hspace{.91 in}$ one needs to replace the ​ o(1) s ​ with c and assert the existence of a positive $\hspace{1.38 in}$ constant c before quantifying over the adversaries. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @DheerajMPai : ​ See my previous comment. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: I have made the change you suggested. 1.) Is it correct now? 2.) Could you elaborate your comment (i.e., how non-uniformity leads to equivalence) --- I don't quite grasp the difference.

Comment: "that the" ​ should be replaced with ending the sentence and starting a new sentence. ​ Otherwise, it seems to be correct now. ​ I wrote up a proof [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293100/232555). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Are $1 \over s$ and $\epsilon$ interchangeable? Essentially this question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46545/security-notion-subexponential-security . @RickyDemer