# The notion of sub-exponential security

Tags: provable-security, security-definition, software-obfuscation, io

I have been reading [a paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/882.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjw_8Xy_Z7TAhXKpI8KHewLCagQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNEh2tIbgZjGPXVDguIzYRBEnyLpmQ&sig2=DR1LvKWawYqPunQZrpPIRw) where they construct probabilistic IO (indistinguishability obfuscation) from sub exponential IO. I want to know if the following two notions of sub-exponential security equivalent?

1. A scheme is sub-exponentially secure if a PPT adversary doesn't get more than 1/subexp(x) advantage.
2. A scheme is sub-exponentially secure if an adversary with sub-exponential computational power doesn't get more than negligible(x) advantage.

(x is security parameter)

The paper defines sub exp secure as defined in 1. But I have come across several notions where they define definition 2 for sub-exponential secure scheme.

Please clarify if both are equivalent. If yes please let me know the proof. If not then where does the equivalence fail?

Comment: What is "io"? It'd make your question understandable for those who don't like clicking on links.

Comment: IO means indistinguishability Obfuscation. It is the topic on which current Cryptographic research is going on. As it was recent topic there are not much information on web. But I'll soon create a wiki for the same in SE as well as on Wikipedia. I'm really sorry for that.@kodlu

Comment: Here are some good references.             http://bristolcrypto.blogspot.in/2013/10/indistinguishability-obfuscation.html   https://www.quantamagazine.org/20150902-indistinguishability-obfuscation-cryptographys-black-box/.   @kodlu

Comment: But I don't think the knowledge of iO is required for this question. I just wanted to know of 2 different notions of security are equivalent@kodlu

Comment: Does the paragraph after Def. 2.1 answer your question?

Comment: @K.G. which paragraph?

Comment: @DheerajMPai "We note that the sub-exponential indistinguishability defined above is weaker than usual sub- exponential hardness assumptions in that the distinguishing gap only need to be small for PPT distinguishers, rather than sub-exponential time distinguishers."

Comment: @K.G. did you mean that definition 1 is a weaker definition than 2? I really don't feel so. As in two the advantage that the adversary gains is <1/poly(x) in 2 while it is 1/subexponential (x) in 1.

Comment: Retry subexponentially many times and get non-negligible success.

Comment: Leo's comment is enough to show "(1) is weaker than or equal to (2)." In the other direction, just note that (1) makes no security claims about adversaries running in super-polynomial time, so (2) is clearly stronger.

Comment: @DanielApon Just making a claim about super-polynomial time adversaries doesn't make it stronger, does it? You can make a claim like "every exponential-time adversary has advantage 1", which is not very strong.

Comment: **Case A:** Poly-time adversaries have negl adv; and for some 'nice' definition of "slightly-superpolynomial-time," such adversaries have advantage 1-negl.

**Case B:** Even "slightly-superpolynomial adversaries" have advantage at most negl. (This *implies* that poly-time adversaries must have adv at most negl as well.)

**So:** Yeah, it does make the 'underlying claim/assumption' strictly stronger.

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast I would be fascinated if you were aware of a "wholly-generic proof" that negl advantage at poly-time implies negl advantage at slightly-superpolynomial time... (I believe this is not the case, but you're welcome to help me separate P and NP if you'd like.. :-))

Comment: @DanielApon I'm not aware of such a proof, but it's not relevant either. Your *Case A* and *Case B* do not reflect the situation in the question. In 1) the adversary is polynomial with 1/subexp advantage, while in 2) the adversary is sub-exponential with 1/poly advantage. Notice the distinction in the advantage, which you are not making. I can define 3) Every adversary has advantage 1, which by your line of reasoning is the strongest definition of the three (since it makes the assumption that exponential time adversaries have advantage 1). This is of course nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

Since noone has written down an answer, I'll give it a go.

There are two important parts of your (or of any) security definitions:

1. An adversary $\mathcal{A}$, with bounded computational power;
2. A bound ${\tt negl}(x)$ on the advantage of $\mathcal{A}$.

These lead to two important observations:

1. The more power we give $\mathcal{A}$, the stronger our security notion;
2. The tighter ${\tt negl}(x)$, the stronger our security notion.

Ideally, you'd give $\mathcal{A}$ unlimited power, and show that he can achieve 0 advantage.

What does this look like in your definitions? Let's first consider $\mathcal{A}$. In (1), your adversary has polynomial computing power. In (2), your adversary has sub-exponential computational power. From this perspective, (2) makes a *weaker* assumption on the adversary, and thus would provide a *stronger* security guarantee than (1).

But as mentioned, the security does not only depend on the adversary. In (1), the function ${\tt negl}_1(x)=1/{\tt subexp}(x)$. In (2), there is no definition of ${\tt negl}_2$. I'd say there are two options:

1. ${\tt negl}_2(x)\leq{\tt negl}_1(x)$. Then (2) makes a weaker assumption on the adversary *and* has a tighter bound on the advantage. Thus (2) gives a stronger security guarantee.
2. ${\tt negl}_2(x)\gt{\tt negl}_1(x)$. Now (2) makes a weaker assumption on the adversary, but (1) has a tighter bound on the advantage. In this case I'd say neither is better. It's basically saying "if we give the adversary more power, he can get more advantage". It would probably depend on context which of the two is applicable.

---

**Edit:** I may have misunderstood your question, if you mean (2) to have negligible advantage according to the usual definition. In that case the above is probably obvious to you, and does not help at all towards your question. I guess I'll just leave it in case it helps someone else..

Comment: In (2) negligible is probably taken to be the [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function) of a negligible function, i.e. $< \frac{1}{\mathrm{poly}(x)}$ for all polynomials.

Comment: @Mark I guess so, just didn't want to make the assumption. Also, anyone care to elaborate on the downvote?

Comment: Considering what Mark mentioned in his comment. Can you say one of the above definition is stronger than the other? @CurveEnthusiast

Comment: @DheerajMPai I'm not completely agreeing with Leo's and Anton's comments. But since I don't consider myself an expert here, I'm reluctant to present my version as the right one. At least using the arguments in my answer, you cannot decide which is stronger.